# Invoke issue using RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I've created a notepad application in c# using the task parallel library. I'm trying to implement a spell checker on my application. The problem I have now is that

```
rtb.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
```

and

```
rtb.SelectionColor = color;
```

gets invoked more then once. Hence my UI freezes up at times. Therefore I applied the async wait for a part of the method. `rtb` is the RichTextBox object. Is there any other way I can get around this.

```
public string spellchecker() {
    string rb = string.Empty;
    using(Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_US.dic")) {
        Parallel.ForEach(Regex.Matches(GetRTBText(), @"\w+").Cast<Match>(), async match => {
            string word = match.Value;
            Color color;
            if (!hunspell.Spell(word)) {
                color = Color.Red;
            } else {
                color = Color.Black;
            }
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
                rtb.Select(match.Index, match.Length);
                rtb.SelectionColor = color;
            }));
            string t = await Task.Run(() => ff());
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
                rb = rtb.Text;
            }));
        });
    }
    return rb;
}

public string ff() {
    string x = String.Empty;
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
        rtb.SelectionStart = rtb.TextLength; // Resetting the selection.
        rtb.SelectionLength = 0;

        x = rtb.Text;
    }));
    return x;
}

public string GetRTBText() {
    string text = string.Empty;

    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() {
        RichTextBox rtb = null;
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
        if (tp != null) {
            rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }

        text = rtb.Text;
    }));

    return text;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, if two Invoke() calls can freeze your UI then you'll have to look elsewhere.  Quite doubtful that a library like Hunspell is thread-safe.

Comment: You are calling `Parallel.ForEach` from the UI thread and then trying to access the already busy *UI* thread again. Deadlock. You *can't* update the UI from a background thread. If you want to find spelling errors or add highlighting in a document, check the *document* in the background, not the UI control that displays it. Once you have all the ranges you want, update the UI.

Comment: BTW `Parallel.ForEach` uses the current thread as well. It's meant for parallel processing, not background processing after all. Remove all calls to `Invoke`. Simply copy the text from the RTFbox into a variable and make the searches you want on it but *don't* try to modify the UI.  If you really need parallel processing call the entire method using `Task.Run`